# Selecting dates in a data.table for new column in r

Tags: r, date, data.table

I have a data table with 65 variables. I want to create a new column for Semester which is allocated to semester 1 all IDs dated before 2015-03-31 (all others are Semester 2).

```
students<-data.table(studid=c(1:6) ,FAC = c("IT","SCIENCE","LAW","IT","COMMERCE","COMMERCE"),dates = c("2010-12-01","2010-03-01", "2010-03-01","2010-05-20", "2010-03-01","2010-03-31"))
```

I have set the date class:

```
students$dates<-as.Date(students$dates)
```

I have then specified the new column:

```
students[,Semester:=2,]
```

Then I have tried:

```
students$Semester[students$dates < 2015-05-31]<-1
```

But this does not work. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend start using `data.table` proper syntax. All of these `$`, `<-` etc. is base R syntax which doesn't take advantage of `data.table` capabilities. Please read the vignettes in [**this link**](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)

In other words, converting to date, for example, is done using (no need in `<-` or `$`)

```
students[, dates := as.IDate(dates)]
```

Which will update your data *by reference*

Second of all, when you just do `2015-05-31`, you are basically just writing an equation: `2015-05-31 = 1979`. Post it in the console and see what you get. In other words, you need to quote `"2015-05-31"` so R will know it's a string (which will be dispatched to a `Date` class later while parsed to `<`).

Finally, here's the solution using `data.table` syntax

```
students[dates < "2015-05-31", Semester := 1]
```